# Customize listview with a smooth moving selector Android

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I am working with an Android box with a remote control.
I want to create a listview with the selector animation like this video, there is a smooth movement of the listview selector when I use remote key code (sorry because I could not describe exactly): 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Fgxisy1w1A&feature=youtu.be
I googled almost one month but could not find any thing usefully.
How should I do? Any tutorial or example for me?
Thanks a lot!